# Custom tooltip for area stacked Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, jquery-tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have used area stacked Highchart in my application.

This is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vyfyk24v/1/)

I have converted the y axis values by place the below code in y axis - labels, but unable to format the tooltip to the same % values

```
 formatter: function(){
      return Math.round(100*this.value / $(this.axis.tickPositions).last()[0]) + '%';
    }
```

But when I tried to apply the same for tool tip, the tooltip itself went invisible. How to apply the percentage to tool tip also. I have tried the below code.

```
 tooltip: {
        shared: false,
        formatter: function() {
            var text = '';
            var pcnt = (this.y / dataSum) * 100;
                text = this.x + ' : <b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(pcnt) +' M</b>';
    return text;
}
    },
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you convert the original data to % ?

Comment: That's what I have done to y axis

Comment: i meant converting the input data and then working with %

Comment: I can convert the input data I must do it in tool tip itself

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vyfyk24v/2/ ? Just to be clear - `this.y` is value of the point, not the sum of all points below + point itself.

Comment: Even I have tried this but the y-axis values are not matching with the tooltip values

Comment: For me they are, but because of the stacking it looks messed. Simply hover any of the points of the "Oceania"-series.

Comment: I guess you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vyfyk24v/3/ - but for me is suggesting really wrong values for the points.. To explain: it loops over all series, gets proper point values and sums them. Later use your magic calculation for displaying the value.

Comment: Thanks I got it. But is that too wrong. Means a little bit inaccurate upto 0.1% is ok. Is this that much wrong or more than that?

Comment: Which value is wrong? And why is that? Note: I didn't change logic for translation value->percentage, I only summed up points which are below hovered one. Demo with more ticks, to see it better: http://jsfiddle.net/vyfyk24v/3/ When I said "suggesting really wrong values"  I meant you are not showing real value of that point, but sum of all points below.